# Low attenuation beer good enough for bottling

Tags: fermentation, beer, final-gravity, attenuation

I recently brewed a new 5 gallon batch of hefeweizen. Measured OG was 1.054, I then racked to secondary fermentation after a couple of weeks, the last week of that had had no visible yeast activity. Measured gravity at that point was 1.014. Based on back of the enveloppe calculations, I am looking at an apparent attenuation of 74% which is a bit on the low side.

I am debating whether it is good enough to bottle or whether I need to throw in some US-05 to clean it up.
Given that it is racked to secondary, and has been for a couple of weeks already.

1- Is it good enough for bottling as is?
2- Is it too late to add more yeast?
3- Should I add more yeast?

Looking for opinions to decide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rules I used to know if yeast is done, is 3 consecutive days with the same gravity measure.  At that point, you can conclude that it is done or stuck, but with a FG of 1.014, it seems low enough to me to call it done.  People do not always reach the attenuation written on the yeast package.

It is never too late to add yeast, but adding more yeast serves no purpose if there is no more sugar to convert.

Measure your gravity for 3 days, and if it stays the same, you can bottle.  You can always wait a few days to let the yeast flocculate and clear the beer a little more if you want.

Comment: Thanks. There has been no movement for a week so it is indeed done or stuck. I'm going to call it done and bottle.